# How to fetch/scan all items from `AWS dynamodb` using node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

How to fetch/scan all items from `AWS dynamodb` using `node.js`. I am posting my code here.

```
var docClient = new aws.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    var params = {
    TableName:"users",
    KeyConditionExpression:"user_status=:status",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":status": "Y"
    }
    };

    var queryExecute = function(callback) {
        docClient.query(params,function(err,result) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err)
                callback(err);
                } else {
                console.log(result);

                if(result.LastEvaluatedKey) {
                    params.ExclusiveStartKey = result.LastEvaluatedKey;
                    queryExecute(callback);
                    } else {
                        callback(err,items);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        queryExecute(callback);
```

This is giving me below error.

```
ValidationException: Query condition missed key schema element: `user_id`.
```

Here primary key is user_id. I don't want to use it with my query condition, because I need to set a value if I mentioned primary key in `KeyConditionExpression`. May be I am wrong. However please suggest me a good way to fetch all items from `dynamodb`, which is having `user_status = "Y"`

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.04.html ?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

If you would like to get the data from DynamoDB without using Hash key value, you need to use `Scan API`.

**Note:** The Scan API reads all the items in the table to get the results. So, it is a costly operation in DynamoDB.

**Alternate Approach :** Use GSI

**Scan Code for the above sceanario:-**

```
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

var params = {
    TableName: "users",
    FilterExpression: "#user_status = :user_status_val",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#user_status": "user_status",
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: { ":user_status_val": 'somestatus' }

};

docClient.scan(params, onScan);
var count = 0;

function onScan(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to scan the table. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {        
        console.log("Scan succeeded.");
        data.Items.forEach(function(itemdata) {
           console.log("Item :", ++count,JSON.stringify(itemdata));
        });

        // continue scanning if we have more items
        if (typeof data.LastEvaluatedKey != "undefined") {
            console.log("Scanning for more...");
            params.ExclusiveStartKey = data.LastEvaluatedKey;
            docClient.scan(params, onScan);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Scan only scans up to 1MB of data, so this code will not work on databases larger than 1MB.

Comment: The code has a recursive call until LastEvaluatedKey is undefined. So, it should work.

Comment: Sorry I missed that!

Comment: if (typeof data.LastEvaluatedKey != "undefined") You can just do: if (data.LastEvaluatedKey)

Comment: While this seems to work, I think it would be a lot better if this answer would actually return the data, instead of just printing it to the console. It's not necessarily easy for people new to JS or functional programming to come up with a solution from here which actually returns the data (via callbak) to the calling function.

Comment: Agree with @JuhaKervinen, it's better to return data. Hank's answer does that and is much more concise.

Comment: This solution is great for those of us who need a synchronous approach using recursion.

Answer (score 123):

This is working for me:

```
export const scanTable = async (tableName) => {
    const params = {
        TableName: tableName,
    };

    const scanResults = [];
    let items;
    do{
        items = await documentClient.scan(params).promise();
        items.Items.forEach((item) => scanResults.push(item));
        params.ExclusiveStartKey = items.LastEvaluatedKey;
    }while(typeof items.LastEvaluatedKey !== "undefined");
    
    return scanResults;
};
```

Comment: This works but some best-practice improvements: make `scanResults` a `const`, change `!=` to `!==`, make `items` a `const` and declare it inside the loop with a separate variable outside the do loop for storing the LastEvaluatedKey.

Comment: You cant assign to constant "items" inside the loop, make it "let" instead. Also you can use better syntax to add multiple items in array: scanResults.push(...items.Items), here you must also check if items.Items is not undefined before pushing.

Comment: May i ask what is the line `params.ExclusiveStartKey = items.LastEvaluateKey` for?

Comment: @Jarrett that is for pagination of results, and allows you to keep track of where to start from for the next scan operation. Scan in dDB will return up to 1 MB of data, or the number of records specified by the `Limit` parameter. If the table contains more records, then you will need to grab ExclusiveStartKey and pass it in as LastEvaluatedKey for the next query to start scanning from that location. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html

Comment: I'm getting an error:-
`Property 'ExclusiveStartKey' does not exist on type '{ TableName: any; }'.
params.ExclusiveStartKey = items.LastEvaluatedKey;` How are you referring to a key which is not declared in the `params` object?

Comment: Just in case someone is looking for this scenario. You may be using TypeScript to get this error, you may create an interface or a custom type and make ExclusiveStartKey as optional prop and then have this interface for params, this should fix the issue.

Comment: `items =  await documentClient.scan(params).promise();` - "attempt to assign to const or readonly variable"

Comment: @Sh4dy  You can use `var params = { TableName: tableName, ExclusiveStartKey: null };` to get rid of typescript error, `Property ExclusiveStartKey' does not exist on type '{ TableName: any; }`.

Answer (score 14):

AWS documentation example didn't work for me. @Hank approach did the trick.

Using handler inside a lambda:

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
    // optional tuning - 50% faster(cold) / 20% faster(hot)
    apiVersion: '2012-08-10',
    sslEnabled: false,
    paramValidation: false,
    convertResponseTypes: false
});

const tableName = 'series';

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    let params = { TableName: tableName };

    let scanResults = [];
    let items;

    do {
        items = await docClient.scan(params).promise();
        items.Items.forEach((item) => scanResults.push(item));
        params.ExclusiveStartKey = items.LastEvaluatedKey;
    } while (typeof items.LastEvaluatedKey != "undefined");

    callback(null, scanResults);
};
```

Answer (score 12):

Using Promises and async

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
aws.config.update({ region: 'us-east-1' });
const documentClient = new aws.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

const scanAll = async (params) => {
  let lastEvaluatedKey = 'dummy'; // string must not be empty
  const itemsAll = [];
  while (lastEvaluatedKey) {
    const data = await documentClient.scan(params).promise();
    itemsAll.push(...data.Items);
    lastEvaluatedKey = data.LastEvaluatedKey;
    if (lastEvaluatedKey) {
      params.ExclusiveStartKey = lastEvaluatedKey;
    }
  }
  return itemsAll;
}
```

Use like this

```
const itemsAll = scanAll(params);
```

The code is the same for query (just replace scan with query)

Answer (score 6):

I use promises like this:

```
let AWS = require('aws-sdk');
let docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

async function dbRead(params) {
    let promise = docClient.scan(params).promise();
    let result = await promise;
    let data = result.Items;
    if (result.LastEvaluatedKey) {
        params.ExclusiveStartKey = result.LastEvaluatedKey;
        data = data.concat(await dbRead(params));
    }
    return data;
}
```

and to use it:

```
let params = {
  TableName: 'Table'
};
let data = await dbRead(params);
```

Comment: In order to understand recursion, you must first understand recursion.

Answer (score 6):

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
    // optional tuning - 50% faster(cold) / 20% faster(hot)
    apiVersion: '2012-08-10',
    sslEnabled: false,
    paramValidation: false,
    convertResponseTypes: false,
    region: 'us-east-2' // put your region
});
const tableName = 'tableName'; // put your tablename

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    let params = { TableName: tableName };

    let scanResults = [];
    let items;

    do {
        items = await docClient.scan(params).promise();
        items.Items.forEach((item) => scanResults.push(item));
        params.ExclusiveStartKey = items.LastEvaluatedKey;
    } while (typeof items.LastEvaluatedKey != "undefined");

    callback(null, scanResults);
};
```

Comment: I like this approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A node express solution that returns the data in JSON format:

```
let datapack=[];
item = {
        TableName: ddbTable,
        FilterExpression: "aws = :e AND begins_with ( Id, :t )",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":t"    :   "contact",
            ":e"    :   aws
        },
        ProjectionExpression: "Id,FirstName,LastName,cEmail",
    };
    docClient.scan(item, onScan);
    function onScan(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Unable to scan the table. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        } else {        
            datapack = datapack.concat(data.Items);
            });
            if (typeof data.LastEvaluatedKey != "undefined") {
                item.ExclusiveStartKey = data.LastEvaluatedKey;
                docClient.scan(item, onScan);
            } else {
                res.json(datapack);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an answer that will deliver indexed results rather than using an expensive scan, also in JSON format node/express. Note use of docClient.query:

```
 datapack=[];
    item = {
        TableName: ddbTable,
        IndexName: "cEmailIndex",
        KeyConditionExpression : "aws = :e AND begins_with ( cEmail, :t )",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":t"    :   search,
            ":e"    :   aws
        },
        ProjectionExpression: "Id,FirstName,LastName,cEmail",
    };
    docClient.query(item, onScan);
    function onScan(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Unable to scan the table. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        } else {
            datapack = datapack.concat(data.Items);
            if (typeof data.LastEvaluatedKey != "undefined") {
                item.ExclusiveStartKey = data.LastEvaluatedKey;
                docClient.query(item, onScan);
            } else {
                // console.log(JSON.stringify(datapack));
                res.json(datapack);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: note: this example and the next still works if you have more data provided then a single scan can handle. Be aware of the dynamodb memory limitations.

Comment: Hi, i followed this and i am getting results back. only issue is LastEvaluatedKey returned in query is always same for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the ScanPaginator from [@aws/dynamodb-query-iterator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws/dynamodb-query-iterator):

```
import { ScanPaginator } from '@aws/dynamodb-query-iterator';
import DynamoDB = require('aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb');

const paginator = new ScanPaginator(
  new DynamoDB.DocumentClient(),
  {
    TableName: "users",
    FilterExpression: "#user_status = :user_status_val",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      "#user_status": "user_status",
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: { ":user_status_val": 'somestatus' }
  }
);

for await (const page of paginator) {
    // do something with `page`, e.g. myFunction(page.Items)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For those who are NOT USING AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient, this solution will work.
I have split the functionality into multiple modules for easy readability and using async/await.

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({
    // update table region here
    region: "us-west-2"
});
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
const performAsynScanOperation = (scanParams) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        dynamodb.scan(scanParams, function (err, responseData) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err)
            } else {
                resolve(responseData)
            }
        })
    })
}

const getAllRecords = async (tableName) => {
    let allItems = [];
    let LastEvaluatedKeyFlag = true;
    let scanParams = { TableName: tableName }
    while (LastEvaluatedKeyFlag) {
        let responseData = await performAsynScanOperation(scanParams)
        let batchItems = responseData.Items;
        allItems = allItems.concat(batchItems);
        if (responseData.LastEvaluatedKey) {
            LastEvaluatedKeyFlag = true;
            console.log('LastEvaluatedKey', responseData.LastEvaluatedKey)
            scanParams.ExclusiveStartKey = responseData.LastEvaluatedKey
        } else {
            LastEvaluatedKeyFlag = false;
        }
    }
    return allItems;
}
getAllRecords('<Name of table>').then((allItems)=>{
  console.log(allItems)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a drop-in replacement to scan all records:

```
const scanAll = async (params) => {
    let all = [];
    while (true) {
        let data = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            db.scan(params, function (err, data) {
                if (err)
                    reject(err);
                else
                    resolve(data);
            });
        });
        all = all.concat(data.Items);
        if (data.LastEvaluatedKey)
            params.ExclusiveStartKey = data.LastEvaluatedKey;
        else
            break;
    }
    return all;
};
```

Usage:

```
scanAll(query)
    .catch((err) => {

    })
    .then((records) => {

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The scan method reads every item in the table and returns all the data in the table. You can provide an optional filter_expression, so that only the items matching your criteria are returned. However, the filter is applied only after the entire table has been scanned. [ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.04.html#GettingStarted.NodeJs.04.Scan)

I'm sharing refactored `onScan` function hope it helps.

```js
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

AWS.config.update({
    region: "us-west-2",
    endpoint: "http://localhost:8000"
});

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

async function read() {
        const params = {
            TableName: "tableName"
            // options can be passed here e.g.
            // FilterExpression: "#yr between :start_yr and :end_yr",
        };

        let items = [];
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            function onScan(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error("Unable to scan the table. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
                    reject();
                } else {
                    items = items.concat(data.Items);

                    // continue scanning if we have more items, because
                    // scan can retrieve a maximum of 1MB of data
                    if (typeof data.LastEvaluatedKey !== "undefined") {
                        params.ExclusiveStartKey = data.LastEvaluatedKey;
                        docClient.scan(params, onScan);
                    } else {
                        resolve(items);
                    }
                }
            }
            docClient.scan(params, onScan);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

An async example using typescript:

```
import { AttributeValue, DynamoDB, ScanCommandInput, ScanCommandOutput } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";

// Create an Amazon DynamoDB service object.
const AWS_REGION = process.env.REGION ?? "<your-default-region>";
const ddb = new DynamoDB({ region: AWS_REGION });

export async function scanTable(tableName: string): Promise<Record<string, AttributeValue>[]> {
    const params: ScanCommandInput = {
        TableName: tableName
    };

    const scanResults: Record<string, AttributeValue>[] = [];
    let items: ScanCommandOutput;
    do {
        items =  await ddb.scan(params);
        items.Items?.forEach((item) => scanResults.push(item));
        params.ExclusiveStartKey  = items.LastEvaluatedKey;
    } while (typeof items.LastEvaluatedKey !== "undefined");

    return scanResults;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the code from @Ioannis Tsiokos

This function will return data structure like the normal scan but will scan all the data:

```
const scanAll = async (params) => {
  try {
    // string must not be empty
    let lastEvaluatedKey = 'notEmpty';
    let itemsAll = {
      Items: [],
      Count: 0,
      ScannedCount: 0
    };
    while (lastEvaluatedKey) {
      const data = await docClient.scan(params).promise();
      console.log('data', JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
      const { Items, Count, ScannedCount } = data;
      itemsAll = {
        ...data,
        ...{ Items: [...itemsAll.Items, ...(Items ? [...Items] : [])] },
        ...(Count
          ? { Count: itemsAll.Count + Count }
          : { Count: itemsAll.Count }),
        ...(ScannedCount
          ? { ScannedCount: itemsAll.ScannedCount + ScannedCount }
          : { ScannedCount: itemsAll.ScannedCount })
      };
      lastEvaluatedKey = data.LastEvaluatedKey;
      if (lastEvaluatedKey) {
        params.ExclusiveStartKey = lastEvaluatedKey;
      }
    }
    return itemsAll;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(
      'Unable to scan the table. Error JSON:',
      JSON.stringify(err, null, 2)
    );
  }
};
```

How to use:

```
 let resp = await scanAll(params);
```