# How to query dynamo db without primary or sort key?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to query a dynamo db table without a Primary partition key
Primary sort key

Those are in my table

```
Primary partition key   userid (String)
Primary sort key    jobcodeid (String)
```

This table also contain a key jobid.

So i want to make a query which looks like this.

```
  var opts  = {
          'ConsistentRead': true,
          TableName : 'interviews',
          KeyConditionExpression: "jobid = :jobid",
          ExpressionAttributeValues: { ":jobid": {"S":jobid} },
        }
```

I am using this code

```
  dynamodb.query(opts, function(err, data) {
  if(err){
   //somthing
   }else{
   //Somthing
   }
 }
```

But the above query returning an error like this.

```
ValidationException: Query condition missed key schema element
```

How can I execute this query?

Comment: What you want to do is scan the table: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html. Querying a DynamoDB table must always be done using the primary key. But be careful with the scan operation since it might be very expensive depending on your table size. It seems that your table layout doesn't quite fit your queries so I suggest you think about a different layout that lets you efficiently query jobs by ID.

Comment: @Makkes Can you give me an example with the scan in node js

Comment: No. You will find a vast amount of documentation using Google. Start here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.04.html Also, I urge you to get to know the basics of DynamoDB, especially with regards to proper table layout, query performance etc.

Comment: Hi thank you for your help i have solved the problem. Best,  This helped me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44589967/how-to-fetch-scan-all-items-from-aws-dynamodb-using-node-js Amazon is very good in documentation :)

Comment: Be very aware of the cost and latency associated with scan. You should probably use a Global Secondary Index, then you can query efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very popular question, with over 5000 people having read it, so I think it's time that it has an answer for the benefit of future readers - and not just comments.

DynamoDB has two distinct operations: [Scan](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html) and [Query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html). `Scan` scans the *entire* table, whereas `Query` can efficiently narrow down on one specific **partition key** (it can still return a huge number of items, because there can be a huge number of items with the same partition key).

Because you don't have a specific partition key you want to scan (`jobid` is your sort key, not your partition key), you'll need to use the `Scan` operation and read the entire table.

This also means that the operation will be very expensive: A `Scan` reads, and charges you for reading, every single item in your database. Even if you pass a `FilterExpression` and eliminate most of the items as non interesting, DynamoDB still reads each one and filters it - and therefore charges you for it.

One of the reasons why this scan will be expensive is that the `Scan` operation **does not** support the `KeyConditionExpression` option that a `Query` has which could have, in some cases, reduced the cost of this scan: Your query involves looking for a specific *sort key* (`jobid = :jobid`) in each partition. If partitions are each fairly long, DynamoDB could have looked up `jobid = :jobid` in each partition without reading the entire partition - and not charge you for reading the entire partition.

Finally, a general piece of advice: The key to designing applications on DynamoDB is to first consider the types of queries you have, and then design the data layout to make these queries efficient. In your case, it seems the data model is inappropriate for this type of queries - so if they are common, you should probably rethink your data layout. For example making `jobid` a partition key, or adding a GSI for `jobid`, or other changes depending on what your data actually has and what other queries you need to do on it.