# DynamoDB scan shows fewer items than DynamoDB console

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Why does a scan with nodejs shows just 3 result, while the dynamodb admin tool shows 9

```
var params = {
    TableName: process.env.DYNAMODB_TABLE_LIGHTHOUSE,
    FilterExpression: '#blickArticleId = :valblickArticleId AND #firstFolder = :valfirstFolder',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        '#blickArticleId': 'blickArticleId',
        '#firstFolder': 'firstFolder'
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':valblickArticleId': 'null',
        ':valfirstFolder': 'null'
    },
  };

  const queryResponse = await dynamoDb.scan(params).promise()
```

isnt that the same

[image]

Comment: Is LastEvaluatedKey present and not empty in the (mis-named) queryResponse?

Comment: "Count":3,"ScannedCount":29,"LastEvaluatedKey":{"id":"db21e190-70d0-11e9-8e71-c142a0fbc609"}}  looks good

Comment: OK,  so you need to scan for the remaining items. The presence of a non-null LastEvaluatedKey indicates that DynamoDB results are paginated. The AWS DynamoDB console is presumably doing the pagination for you. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44589967/how-to-fetch-scan-all-items-from-aws-dynamodb-using-node-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as jarmod mentioned pagination is the solution:

```
const getLalalalalal = async () => {
  var params = {
    TableName: process.env.DYNAMODB_TABLE_LIGHTHOUSE,
    FilterExpression: '#blickArticleId = :valblickArticleId AND #firstFolder = :valfirstFolder',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        '#blickArticleId': 'blickArticleId',
        '#firstFolder': 'firstFolder'
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':valblickArticleId': 'null',
        ':valfirstFolder': 'null'
    },
  };

  return await scanTable(params)
}

const scanTable = async (params) => {
  let scanResults = [];
  let items;
  do {
      items = await dynamoDb.scan(params).promise();
      items.Items.forEach((item) => scanResults.push(item));
      params.ExclusiveStartKey = items.LastEvaluatedKey;
  } while(typeof items.LastEvaluatedKey != "undefined");

  return scanResults;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure , your scanned content is not more than 1MB ?.

> If the total number of scanned items exceeds the maximum data set size
>   limit of 1 MB, the scan stops and results are returned to the user
>   with a LastEvaluatedKey

Then you can scan the remaining items by using  LastEvaluatedKey.

Answer (score 1):

Your code needs to scan for the remaining items. The presence of a non-null `LastEvaluatedKey` indicates that DynamoDB results are paginated. The AWS DynamoDB console is presumably doing the pagination for you.

Here is an example of code to [fetch all items if paginated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44589967/how-to-fetch-scan-all-items-from-aws-dynamodb-using-node-js).