# How to get the item from dynamo db if its not primary or sort_key

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

My dynamodb table has `user` as `partition_key` and `sort_key` as `Time`

I am searching for the `type` which is in  'Product Team' from the dynamodb in prescribed format

Below i have added 3 items from  the dynamo db table

```
{ "user": "a@gmail.com", "type": "Product Team", "message": "Developer", "employeeId": "101", "message_requested":"Requested for the 192.168.1.1 access" "Time": "2021-01-08 12:09:54.986542" },

{ "user": "a@gmail.com", "type": "Product Team", "message": "Developer", "employeeId": "101", "message_requested":"Requested for the 192.168.1.2 access" "Time": "2021-01-09 12:10:54.986542" },

{ "user": "c@gmail.com", "type": "Ops Team", "message": "Tester", "employeeId": "102", "message_requested":"Requested for the 192.168.1.1 access" "Time": "2021-01-08 11:09:54.986542" }
```

Expected out is

```
{"user":"a@gmail.com",
"params":[{"message_requested":"Requested for the 192.168.1.1 access"
  "Time": "2021-01-08 12:09:54.986542"},
{"message_requested":"Requested for the 192.168.1.2 access"
  "Time": "2021-01-09 12:10:54.986542"}]
}
```

Below is the code to extract the items from the dynamodb table

```
def details(type):
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    client = boto3.client('dynamodb')
    table = dynamodb.Table("my_db_table_name")
    #res = client.get_item(
    #            TableName=table,
    #            Key={
    #                'type': {'S': 'Product Team'
    #                       }})
    res = table.scan(FilterExpression=Attr("type").eq("Product Team"))
    return res
```

Comment: for get_item to work you need to have primary key or composite key [ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html) . What you want can be accomplished with [scan](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html)   or changing sort key. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44589967/how-to-fetch-scan-all-items-from-aws-dynamodb-using-node-js) for more info.

Comment: @ManavChhibber update the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two options:

1. Use scan to perform search in the table. In this case the search
   time will be significant compared with Primary/Composite key.
2. Make a [Global Secondary Index](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) and make
   Primary/Composite key the fields that you need.

Comment: I know you are asking about Python - but there is a Java V2 example that uses a Secondary index here: https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javav2/example_code/dynamodb/src/main/java/com/example/dynamodb/EnhancedScanRecordsWithExpression.java