# Property 'ExclusiveStartKey' does not exist on type '{ TableName: any; }'

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am trying to scan a DynamoDB table which may be more than 1 MB, so I'm using `ExclusiveStartKey`. I've been going through all the examples in [How to fetch/scan all items from `AWS dynamodb` using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44589967/how-to-fetch-scan-all-items-from-aws-dynamodb-using-node-js/54834851) but I'm getting an error in this line: `scanParams.ExclusiveStartKey = items.LastEvaluatedKey;`

```
src/services/DynamoDB.ts:33:18 - error TS2339: Property 'ExclusiveStartKey' does not exist on type '{ TableName: any; }'.

33       scanParams.ExclusiveStartKey = items.LastEvaluatedKey;
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Found 1 error.
```

This kind of makes sense because the `scanParams` usually have just the table name and no other keys. So, how do I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint the shape of `params` to Typescript:

```js
const params = {
  TableName: tableName,
  ExclusiveStartKey: undefined, // <-- add this
};
```

Or, if you want to get really fancy, import and use the library's defined type. If you are using the [doc client from SDK v3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/modules/_aws_sdk_lib_dynamodb.html#scancommandinput-2), for example:

```js
import {ScanCommandInput} from '@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb'

const params: ScanCommandInput = {
  TableName: tableName,
};
```