# Issue with dynamo db scan not returning results

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

New to Dynamo DB and have spent a bit of time searching Stackoverflow for my issue but not having any luck. I currently have a pretty default setup table have some data being populated in (confirmed by using the item explorer tab in the console). I was referencing the AWS Dynanmo SDK and also this post [stackOverflow 44589967](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44589967/how-to-fetch-scan-all-items-from-aws-dynamodb-using-node-js) to basically return the first item from the table. Does not matter which item just any item. So here is very basic lambda, and I did confirm permissions:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'us-east-1'});
exports.handler = async function(event, context) {
   let result = await ddb.scan({
        "TableName": "DynamoDB_Project",
        "Limit": 1,
      })

console.log(result);
}
```

I am getting null and wondering if its actually how I am storing the data

[screen shot of table explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTMFB.png)

which is similar to my scan

```
await ddb.put({
        "TableName": "DynamoDB_Project",
        "DateTempHumid": {
            "Date": event.date,
            "Humidty": event.humidty,
            "Temperature": event.temperature
          },
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to add the `.promise()` function to the string of calls?

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'us-east-1'});
exports.handler = async function(event, context) {
   let result = await ddb.scan({
        "TableName": "DynamoDB_Project",
        "Limit": 1,
      }).promise(); // HERE

    console.log(result);
}
```

Hope that helps